# How to tell if Access VBA is password protected

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am building an Access add-in that can import/export Access objects from the open database application.  I am using the undocumented `SaveAsText` and `LoadFromText` commands to work with the objects.  If the **VBA of the Access application** has a password on it, the commands will fail.  I'm looking for a way to programmatically determine if the VBA is password protected before my routine begins.

Note, this question is *not about a password on the Access database itself*.  I am referring to the protection that is set from VBA project properties dialog like the image below.

[image]

Check this link if you need to [Determine if an MS Access Database is Password Protected](https://www.devhut.net/2014/05/02/determine-if-an-ms-access-database-is-password-protected/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that will return TRUE if the active VBA project is password protected.

```vb
Function ProtectedVBProject() As Boolean
' Returns TRUE if the VBA of the project is password protected.

    Dim VBC As Integer
    VBC = -1
    On Error Resume Next
    VBC = Application.VBE.VBProjects(1).VBComponents.Count ' Project count may be Base 1

    On Error GoTo 0
    If VBC = -1 Then
        ProtectedVBProject = True
    Else
        ProtectedVBProject = False
    End If
End Function
```

Here is an example of how to call this function:

```
' Stop if the VBA is protected with a password.
If ProtectedVBProject Then
    MsgBox "It appears that the source code is password protected.  Please open" _
        & " the Visual Basic editor and enter the VBA password for the active database." _
        , vbExclamation, "Object Locked!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

If the add-in is only going to be used by myself or other developers and the code is not compiled into a .mde or .accde, this next example gives the user the option to enter the password on the spot and then continue.  I probably don't need to tell you that using `STOP` in published code is generally bad practice.

```
' Stop if the VBA is protected with a password and ask if the user wants to unlock it.
If ProtectedVBProject Then
    Dim strMsg as String
    strMsg = "It appears that the source code is password protected." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to enter the VBA password now?"

    Select Case MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo Or vbExclamation Or vbDefaultButton1, "Object Locked")

        Case vbYes
            '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
            '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
            '=-=-=
            '=-=-=    ENTER THE VBA PASSWORD FOR THE ACTIVE DATABASE
            '=-=-=    THEN PRESS F5 TO RESUME THE CODE EXECUTION
            '=-=-=
            '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
            '=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
            Stop        ' Press F5 to continue.  Do not remove this line.

        Case vbNo
            Exit Sub            
    End Select
End If
```